# Bind Secondary Groups to Active Directory w/ Unix Extensions

Tags: macos, active-directory

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 w/ Active Directory and Unix Extensions. I have several linux/bsd hosts already connected to the domain via ldap and mapping the uid/gid/secondary groups properly.

I'm running a few mac's on 10.9 and 10.10 beta, I'm trying to figure out if its possible to map secondary Group IDs to the AD UnixGID and not the GID that AD creates..

for example, if i run `id mikedevita` on a linux box it gives me this:

```
% id mikedevita                                                                                                                                                         
uid=40001(mikedevita) gid=30000(Domain Users) groups=30001(Domain   Admins),30002(VMWareAdmins)
,30003(VPNUsers),30004(LinuxUsers),30005(media),30006(LinuxAdmins),30000(Domain Users)
```

if i run the same command, `id mikedevita` on my mac it gives this:

```
base% id mikedevita
uid=40001(mikedevita) gid=30000 groups=30000,701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),519395259(DEVITA\media),693256891(DEVITA\MacAdmins),703(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4),501(access_bpf),599473300(DEVITA\VPNUsers),613468898(DEVITA\VMWareAdmins),12(everyone),62(netaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),1446817776(DEVITA\Domain Admins),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),1873589173(DEVITA\RouterAdmins),416683223(DEVITA\Denied RODC Password Replication Group),206(com.apple.access_loginwindow),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)
```

as you can see, the uid, and gid fields are mapped properly (40001, 30000) but all of the domain level groups which the user belongs to as secondary groups don't use the right group ID.

Is there a way to remap this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the user records' gid attribute mapped, but not the group records' gid. You can check this from the command line with `dsconfigad`:

```
$ sudo dsconfigad -show
[...]
Advanced Options - Mappings
  Mapping UID to attribute       = uidNumber
  Mapping user GID to attribute  = gidNumber
  Mapping group GID to attribute = gidNumber
  Generate Kerberos authority    = Enabled
[...]
```

Note the "Mapping group GID to attribute = gidNumber" -- that's what I think you're missing. You can set it from the command line with `sudo dsconfigad -ggid gidNumber`, on with the GUI program /System/Library/CoreServices/Directory Utility.app (click the padlock to authenticate as admin, double-click the Active Directory connector, click the triangle to "Show Advanced Options", click the Mappings tab, then enable "Map group HID to attribute" and set it to "gidNumber").

Comment: Does the Mapping change the UID and GID locally to match the one in AD?

Comment: @Johnny: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. For AD accounts, the Mac *always* uses UIDs and GIDs based on the AD account attributes. If mapping is enabled, it uses the selected AD attributes (generally `uidNumber` and `gidNumber`). If mapping is not enabled, it uses IDs generated from the accounts' UUID. There's never really a "local" ID.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when you don’t explicitly map the gidNumber attribute, it maps the PrimaryGroupID to gid. That’s why you are getting different numbers.